# Square-integrable functions, proofs of $L^2-norm$ properties

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying my way through Apostol for a final.  I have questions on Ex 10.38 through 10.42, but if I can get 10.38 I should be good for the rest.

$f\in L^2(I)$. The $L^2$-norm,  $\|f\|$, is defined by the formula, $\|f\|=(\int_I|f|^2)^{1/2}$.

10.38 If $\lim_{x\to\infty}\|f_n-f\|=0$, prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\|f_n\|=\|f\|$.

I was starting by applying the definition of norm to the integral, but I didn't know how to proceed from there. Are there some operations I can perform on the norm before putting the integral in there to simplify? If not, how do I manipulate this equation?

$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\int_I|f_n-f|^2)^{1/2}=0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Theorem 10.55 part (f) from Apostol we get,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\| \le \lim_{n\to\infty}(\|f_n - f\| + \|f\|) = 0 + \|f\| = \|f\|.$$
and
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\| = \lim_{n\to \infty}(\|f_n - f\| + \|f_n\|) \ge \lim_{n\to\infty}\|f\| = \|f\|.$$

Thus by squeeze theorem, $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\| = \|f\|.$

Comment: Thanks!  I knew I was making it more difficult than it needed to be...

Answer (score 1):

If $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ is *any* normed space, then
$$
\left| \|x\|-\|y\| \right| \leq \|x-y\|
$$
for every $x$, $y \in X$. Just use the triangular inequality twice.